# Ad control does not show anything and disappear on windows phone apps

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have created a windows phone app that support on 7.1 and 8.0 OS. I have added an `AdControl` at the bottom of my app to show ads in my app. While using testing `ApplicationId` and `Adunit Id` it shows default microsoft add on both emulator and my device, but when I use my `ApplicationId` and `Addunit Id` and run on my phone it does not showing add and it'll disappear after some time.

I have seen lots of websites and followed those steps, but its not working.

I am using Visual studio express 2012 for windows phone and 
Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows Phone-ENU version 6.2.960.0.

WMAppManifest.xml capabilities checkbox checked

```
ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER
ID_CAP_MEDIA_LIB
ID_CAP_NETWORKING
ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER
ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT
```

obiously i have enabled all capabilities

Here is my code

mainPage.xaml code:

```
<my:AdControl Visibility="Visible" ErrorOccurred="OnAdError_ErrorOccurred" AdUnitId="10020750" ApplicationId="e1e3c23b-3a59-4119-852e-8ad0a7f78f11" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-12,6,0,0" Name="adControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="480" />
```

and mainPage.cs code

```
using Microsoft.Advertising.Mobile.UI;

namespace WP_AdApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        private AdControl adControl;
        private const string APPLICATION_ID = "e1e3c23b-3a59-4119-852e-8ad0a7f78f11";
        private const string AD_UNIT_ID = "10020750";

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
        }

        private void OnAdError_ErrorOccurred(object sender, Microsoft.Advertising.AdErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("AdControl error: " + e.Error.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

I have testing with `OnAdError_ErrorOccurred` event handler to get errors on ad control. While running I got an error that shows:

> HTTP status error code: Not found (404).

the application ID and Adunit Id are real values and am developing application in india., and

my internet connections are perfect, i have opened  some webpages in IE and works perfect.,

Comment: I hope those aren't your real ID values in your example. Also, the 404 error tells me that you're getting an internal server error... are you trying to load a web page or using HTTP somewhere without checking for `null`?

Comment: Which functions did you enable in your WMAppManifest.xml?

Comment: Did you check that your phone / emulator had internet connection (by opening the IE app for example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your app deployed on the marketplace? If No then ads appear after once the app gets deployed. Till then its simply a 404 server not found error. You can't get the ads till your app do not get deployed on the marketplace. You will keep getting this message till you don't deploy it.

Comment: amu said is exactly right., finally i got ads in my app., thank you for your support